# Dirt bike silencer core cracked/rusted

Tags: motorcycle, exhaust

After removing and disassembling my FMF Factory 4.1 dirt bike silencer, I saw that the inner core was cracked and extremely rusty (having the potential for more cracks). I definitely want to fix this so that I'm not riding with a faulty silencer.

Is there anywhere that I can buy just the core? Or should I just go ahead and spend the money for a new silencer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your local motorcycle dealership a call. FMF does make replacement cores and these are very likely available from your local FMF dealer.

This mfg part number will help you find what you're looking for: 040261

Confirm on their web page: http://www.fmfracing.com/Products/Accessories/334